# Вставить случайные десятичные числа в бд MySQL

Tags: mysql

Нужно вставить в столбец рейтинга случайные числа от 4 до 5, с одним знаком после запятой.

```
UPDATE s_products SET rating=FLOOR(RAND()*(5-4)/4) WHERE id = 755
```

Так не работает, имитация запроса возвращает пустой результат (затронуто 0 строк), хотя товар с айди 755 существует. Поле rating типа float.
В чем может быть проблема, не подскажете? Спасибо!

UPD а вот если в поле rating у товара с данным id уже стоит какое-то число (не 0), то работает. Очень странно.

Comment: а какую роль тут у вас кавычки имеют?

Comment: @teran не обращайте внимания, удалил, без них, кстати, ситуация та же

Comment: *Поле rating типа float* Согласно условиям на значение DECIMAL(2,1) было бы куда как более оправдано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE s_products 
SET rating = FLOOR(40 + (RAND() * 11)) / 10
WHERE id = 755
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dddf3707968110683b44c18c903cc16f